# Expand cursor between one control to another in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to .net.Now i am working on Wpf in .net.

how to expand the cursor between one control to another control in wpf?
I am doing drag and drop operation between two tree views.while dragging tree view item from source to destination ,I want to connect source and destination tree view item with arrow cursor.
whether it is possible or not?if possible please help me with the code.

Comment: than why don't you help us with some code? :P Have you even tried something? 
Show us what you've done :)

Comment: What do you mean by `expand the cursor` and `connect source and destination tree`?

Comment: connecting to points in the different control using arrow according to the mouse movement.